# Business Unit Id cannot be set to null error trying to create equipment record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I was trying to create a facility/equipment with the following code, but i'm getting an error saying "business unit id cannot be set to NULL"

I have only one business Unit created in my crm 2016
Here is my code:

```
string fetchBU = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                  <entity name='businessunit'>
                                    <attribute name='name' />
                                    <attribute name='address1_telephone1' />
                                    <attribute name='websiteurl' />
                                    <attribute name='parentbusinessunitid' />
                                    <attribute name='businessunitid' />
                                    <order attribute='name' descending='false' />
                                  </entity>
                                </fetch>";

EntityCollection resultequipments = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchBU));

if (resultequipments.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    Guid BuId;
    BuId = (Guid)resultequipments.Entities[0]["businessunitid"];
    Entity equipment = new Entity("equipment");
    equipment["name"] = "test";
    equipment["businessunitid"] = BuId;
    _orgService.Create(equipment);
    Console.WriteLine("Facility successfully created");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try hardcoding your business unit id, do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes i hard coded ! but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `businessunitid` attribute in your query result is a primary key, i.e. `Guid` type.

The `businessunitid` attribute in an `equipment` entity is a lookup, which is represented by an `EntityReference` object.

You cannot assign a `Guid` to an `EntityReference` attribute. Modify your code similar to this:

```
EntityCollection businessUnits = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchBU));

if (businessUnits.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    Entity equipment = new Entity("equipment");
    equipment["name"] = "test";
    equipment["businessunitid"] = new EntityReference("businessunit", businessUnits.Entities[0].Id);
    _orgService.Create(equipment);
    Console.WriteLine("Facility successfully created");
}
```